# I want to get User (Client) computer name or any unique key that i verify before login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

`I am using asp.net mvc c# web application, and my task is when user login i get his device name (computer or mobile) and save in data base. when user login again i check the save device name is equal to current device name if yes then login if not then send code via email and when code verify save his current device name in database.`

```
var ip = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] ?? Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
string hostName = computer_name[0].ToString();
string hostName = HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
string hostName = HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

i tried all above code but it get web server name and ip not user local device (laptop,system or mobile) name or ip.

I want to get user device name (system/mobile) and ip``

Comment: It can't be done. Reason read here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656478/capture-device-name