# How to get server host name using Java while starting the server

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to get the server hostname using Java while starting the server.

Before that i was used HTTP servlet request but I cannot get the request during start the server it's shows null pointer exception.

Can you help to get the solution for this.

I want the solution like this.

**localhost:8080 or some other ip server with port**

Comment: You can try `System.out.println(System.getenv("HOSTNAME"));`

Comment: Still I am getting null only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to get hostname in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348711/recommended-way-to-get-hostname-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

your can try this to get hostname

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class HostName {
public static void main(String a[]){
    try {
        InetAddress myHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println(myHost.getHostName());
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956000/768795

Comment: I am getting my system ip and hostname.not my server ip

Comment: you can try   System.out.println(myHost.getHostAddress());