# system.environment.machinename in java?

Tags: java, netbios

Is there a way to get the same thing returned by `system.environment.machinename` in c# -- but in java?

I've tried `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();` and using the JCIFS open source library.

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100266/find-physical-machine-name-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Did you try when using the JCIFS?

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
String host = addr.getHostName();
```

What did you get when you tried

> InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();